# Change path of Firebird Secondary database files

Tags: firebird, database-administration

I have created a Firebird multi-file database
Main Database file `D:\Database\MainDB.fdb`
Secondary files (240 Files) located under `D:\Database\DBFiles\Data001.fdb` to `D:\Database\DBFiles\Data240.fdb`

When copy database to another location and trying to open it Firebird doesn't locate the files if they are not in `D:\` partition
I want Firebird to locate the secondary files under `Database\DBFiels` folder at the new path.

So if I copy the database to `C:\Database\MainDB.fdb`
Firebird would open `Data001.fdb` in new path like `C:\Database\DBFiles` instead of old path in `D:\Database\DBFiles` where they were initially created

Can that be done with Firebird? if not, then how it should be done?

**Update:**

**Finally I found out it's not possiable to change Firebird database secondary files usign Firebird.**

but I found this [Firebird FAQ](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq179/) mention [GLINK](http://www.volny.cz/iprenosil/interbase/ip_ib_download.htm) tool but It doesn't support Firebird 3.x so I didn't test it, and It's not recommended to use it even with supported versions of Firebird.

Comment: Why do you have so many database files? It doesn't make much sense to me, as the Firebird documentations says: _"Nowadays, multi-file databases are considered a throwback. It made sense to use multi-file databases on old file systems where the size of any file is limited. For instance, you could not create a file larger than 4 GB on FAT32."_ Using multiple database files just adds unnecessary complications without real benefit.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I use to many files because this is an embedded database and should work on some old limited systems, and it will be very hard to backup and restore database when it becomes few terabytes, but with make ability of copying and pasting the database files it will be much faster and easier.

Comment: If your embedded use yields so large a database, maybe you should consider moving to a client/server model.

Comment: @Mark why using terabytes of DB in embedded mode seems crazy indeed (though embedded mode was default CS mode on UNIX) and I second the move to standalone server, that would not solve the "i have my databases storage on Win98 FAT32 old system" issue.

Comment: @Arioch'The it's used in Embedded mode on some computers and Server mode on other computers (where the data will be updated) and then updated the embedded database when needed, this is how it works now, I don't know maybe one or 2 years later they will get ride of embedded database and keep server only

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thank you, I will think about it, if there is any good suggestion will be glad to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done what exactly?

UPD. I edited the very vague original question to make clear WHAT the topic starter wants.

1. You can not reliably "copy files with Firebird" - Firebird is not files copying tool. You can to a degree use `EXTERNAL TABLE` for raw files access, but very limited and not upon the database itself.
2. It is dangerous practice to "copy databases" while Firebird is working, because you would only copy part of the data. The recently updated data that is in memory cache but did not yet made it on disk would be lost. The database file would be inconsistent with some data updated and some not yet. When you "copy database files" you have first to shutdown either those databases or even the whole Firebird server.
3. Firebird has it's own tools for moving databases around - and those are called backup/restore tools. Maybe what you need is `nbackup` tool, if `gbak` is too slow for you.
4. Finally, you can list files that comprise the database. You can do it via `gstat` utility or via "Services API" it uses. You also can select from `RDB$FILES` system table. However what would you do after you did it? The very access to the database makes it badly suited for consequent copying (#2). You would perhaps need to shutdown database, turn it to read-only AND single-user state, and only then attach to it and read `RDB$FILES`. And after copying done - you would have to de-shutdown the database. Kinda much more complex than `nbackup`.

---

- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gstat-example-header.html
- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gfix-dbstartstop.html
- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref-appx04-files.html
- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gbak.html
- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/nbackup.html

Comment: I know that, I'm trying to copy embedded database there is no risk at all by copying it, the only problem is the secondary files even when move database to another partition it keeps look for secondary files in same old partition as I showed in my question, so I want it automatically detect secondary files in new database path

Comment: @SaRaFinBas Use gbak. That is what it is for.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i know gbak, but i don't want to backup and restore the database, i can do it but other users can't do it, user should be able to copy/move database to any location, if I use single file database there is no problem the problem start with using multi-file database because the Firebird can not locate the new secondary files location

Comment: @SaRaFinBas If you don't want to backup and restore, why are you copying the database? Copying the database is the correct way of moving a Firebird database. The problem you have with locating the secondary file locations is because Firebird stores the absolute path of these files in its metadata. If you want to relocate them, the only correct way is to backup and restore with gbak specifying those locations.

Comment: you might TRY to change paths in `RDB$FILES` but there is no warranty that would actually work even in FB2 less so in FB3

Comment: 1) instead of gbak - use nbackup. Does not optimize the database, but is much faster. 2) you do not ask users to "use gbak" of course. Instead you make your application use it, or rather to use "Service API" of the Firebird server. The user clicks a button in your application - and your application makes backup-restore as required. 3) probably `nbackup` can also be used via combination of SQL and Services API, not only by running the exe, but I am not sure, just was never interested to check.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel so Firebird can't do it in this way, this is the direct answer, I was hoping there is some tricks to get it to work, Thank you.

Comment: @Arioch'The I don't think it's possible to change it in `RDB$FILES` but I will give it a try, Thank you.

Comment: @Arioch'The I was thinking about this but I thought there will be some think easier for user just like copy and paste, I will make more research about it for 2 more days and will go with this solution if I didn't find Firebird way, Thank you very much.

Comment: @SaRaFinBas Firebird's primary use case is single database file with client/server. Yours is an odd edge case. In any case, how do you expect a Firebird database to just pick up on a OS file move operation.

Comment: @SaRaFinBas think from another perspective: the db server MUST secure the consistency of the data, by any mean necessary. By allowing you to "inject" any random file like it would be part of the database - and your free change of paths to DB shards implies as much as that - the server breaks this warranty it must provide utterly. So, it probably would be very hard to convince here. Its goals are just opposite.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I didn't expect a Firebird database to pick up any OS operation, What I was thinking it's possible to make relative path so it look into root directory of database instead of static file path, like unix shorthand for current directory `./` or `.`.

Comment: @Arioch'The I agree with you, and I understand all that, but it's first time I work with such important database It's very important and i'm the only one will be responsible if it lost or anything wrong happened, So i'm little afraid and confused, I'm sorry if my question was confused, thank very much.guys.

Comment: `and i'm the only one will be responsible if it lost or anything wrong happened` - which implies all those databases are regulary backed up and restored for tests ( you do test restore after backups, don't you? you would detect "unrestorabe backup" before it hits anyone, right? ), so just add there the restore into the new path. When you work with terabytes of very importatnt data and you are "the only on responsible" - then do not hack around. If you used standard ways and lost data - you can blame the vendor. If you used anti-standard ways - you are the scapegoat

Comment: @Arioch'The you are absolute right, It's just very big data, backup, test, restore will take very long time so I was hoping to find another way faster and easier..  but since it's not available I will start thinking how to make auto-backup or maybe double the database or sync it with embedded ones automatically, I'm not sure yet, Thank you very much for your help and your time to reply me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I say it for the 3rd time, if you think gbak is too slow for it explore nbackup, it's cons and pros. But if you won't back-up because "it is huge" then you would be one day blamed for lost of the data even if you would had been coerced to skip backups (or skip test restores).